# Jobs under c4.8xlarge EC2 Cloudformation on AWS taking a while to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jobs, ram

I just instantiated a new c4.8xlarge stack in Cloudformation at AWS-EC2, because use of the c4.xlarge bombed out due to lack of memory.   However, it appears that after 30 minutes, none of the jobs started (are in "qw" status) and my guess is that the RAM and cores have to become available first.

Can a c4.8xlarge stack take a while before the jobs start running?

Answer (score 0):

It worked out that I didn't change the default 0.199 hourly rate (for c4.xlarge) based on the EC2 Instance hourly rates (available at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ ).   Since I specified c4.8xlarge, the rate had to be changed to 1.591, and now the jobs have started.

Comment: So you were using spot instance pricing but neglected to add that to your question?